# How do I find the distribution of random variable that is a floor function?

Tags: probability

If given a measure $\mu=\frac{1}{log2}\rho Leb|_{I}$ where $I=(0,1)/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\rho(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$, how do I find the distribution of the random variable defined as $a_{1}(\alpha)=[\frac{1}{\alpha}]$.

I know it is defined to be $F_{X}(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$. Now in this case I don't know how to deal with this floor function. do I compute $\mathbb{P}([\frac{1}{\alpha}]\leq \alpha)$ and discuss in different cases on $\alpha$?

i guess I need to find the range of my floor function $a_{1}(\alpha)=[\frac{1}{\alpha}]$ which is just $\{\mathbb{N_{\geq1}}\}$

Comment: I think you have a typo in your definition of $\mu$ but I don't see what it is.

Comment: @Ian I guess it was a typo on the set $I$

Comment: No, it's a typo about where the log and the $\rho$ go. Should it be $\frac{1}{\log_2(\rho)} Leb_I$, or is it just $\frac{1}{\ln(2)} \cdot \rho \cdot Leb_I$?

Comment: @Ian it is the latter .

Comment: Parentheses would clarify the matter, then. Anyway, you just need to identify the relevant interval $I_n$ where $\lfloor 1/\alpha \rfloor$ is equal to each natural number $n$ (which will be when $n \leq 1/\alpha<n+1$, of course) and then integrate the probability density over $I_n$. This will give you the PMF.

Comment: @Ian thanks that was really helpful